# Bootstrap datetimepicker not showing calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using *bootstrap* `datepicker` in a *ASP.net MVC* `form`, but not able to see calendar.

I am using *asp.net* bundle and my page source is like this:

`head` element is rendering like this:

```
<title>Site login</title>

<link href="/Scripts/LyncPresence/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/selectize.bootstrap3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Gridmvc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/gridmvc.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/metisMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
//and scripts are 

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootbox.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-touch-punch.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

In *javascript* i initialize `datetime` text box like:

```
$('#fieldName').datetimepicker({ format: 'dd MM yyyy - hh:ii' });
```

I am not able to see calendar, am i missing anything? i believe *JS* and *CSS* in correct order.

Comment: May be you forget some dependencies. read the dependencies section from [here](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Comment: Have you tried taking the necessary `.js` and `.css` files out of the bundle and just put them on the page that you're testing?  Could be something wrong the bundle like updating WebGrease.

Comment: You stated that you are using _bootstrap datepicker_ but your code uses `datetimepicker` method. Moreover can you check which datetimepicker are you using? If you are using [eonasdan-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) change the `format` option to `format: 'DD MM YYYY HH:mm'`.